# How to dynamically resize a React iframe that is embedded in a wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, iframe

I have a react app, that will be embedded as an iframe inside a Wordpress website. The iframe will have dynamic content, hence the size might change. I was wondering if there is any way to do so?

I checked out the iframe-resizer-react but that seems to be a plugin for the react app as the host, whereas my react app is the content and the wordpress is the host for the iframe.

EDIT: At the moment I am trying to embed this React Iframe in a simple html file (havent started the changes on wordpress as I don't have much clue). Trying to use the iframe-resizer pluging, since that seems the most useful.

This is what my host (parent) sample html looks like. Just testing with html, since I figured adding the js on the wordpress should be similar.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent page</title>
    <style>
        iframe {
          width: 1px;
          min-width: 100%;
        }
      </style>
<script scr="./js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is the parent page</h1>
    <iframe src="http://localhost:3000/" id="myIframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</body>


<script>
   iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#myIframe')
</script>
</html>
```

And in the index.html of the react app I have tried to add the following:

```
    <script src="./iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

But this just throws an error on the parent page, `test.html:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: iFrameResize is not defined`

Comment: Give some more information about the wordpress page in which is the iframe (code, page editor used if any...). Also, tell us what you tried to fix your issue.

Comment: Updated the question. I haven't done anything on the wordpress, as you can see in the question above. Trying to embed the react iframe in a simple html and using iframe resizer.

Comment: You typed `scr` instead of `src` when importing `iframeResizer.min.js`.

Comment: Yes. Fixed that now. That solved it. Now will try to embed the same in wordpress.